# Arrays, lists, sets and maps are iterable. What else?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, iterator

Even if only `List` and `Set` implement the interface `Iterable`, I believe that an array, a list, a set and a map are all *iterable* objects, in that we can use them all through a foreach loop:

```
for(String s : new String[0]);
for(String s : new ArrayList<String>());
for(String s : new HashSet<String>());
for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : new HashMap<Integer, String>().entrySet());
```

*The case of `Map` is maybe a bit different, but let consider it as a key-value list (what it actually is).*

Starting with that *iterable understanding*, am I missing a type in the following method?

```
public boolean isIterable(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Object[] || o instanceof Iterable || o instanceof Map;
}
```

In other words, are there any other types that can be iterated through a foreach loop?

Side but resulting question: is that list of types exhaustive?

Comment: Note that in your map example, you don't iterate over the map, you iterate over a `Set<Entry>`, i.e. a set.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Anything that implements the `Iterable<T>` interface is iterable. The [Iterable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) lists many of the core Java classes that do this. And note that this also includes class that you create that implement the interface. I've done this at times if my class contains an ArrayList or other iterable object and I want to conveniently iterate through the contents of this. I simply pass the list's Iterator object as the return result for the iterator() method.

For example:

Person.java

```
class Person {
   private String lastName;
   private String firstName;
   public Person(String lastName, String firstName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Person [lastName=" + lastName + ", firstName=" + firstName + "]";
   }


}
```

MyPeople.java

```
class MyPeople implements Iterable<Person> {
   List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

   // ... other methods and constructor

   @Override
   public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
      return personList.iterator();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, arrays aren't implementing the `Iterable` interface, maps neither (even if we iterate on its entry set, not on itself directly, but that isn't the point). The question was more: are there any type that are not implementing `Iterable` but that are *iterable* with that understanding of *iterable*? I mean, looking through them, from a beginning to an end. When thinking about algorithms, it's common to say "go through a matrix, through a list, through a stack", etc. A matrix is a kind of `Map<Map, Object>`, although `Map` isn't implementing `Iterable`. Hum... you said philosophy?

Comment: @sp00m: map doesn't implement Iterable, and you can't use forEach on Map type, just on the value or key sets that are obtainable.

Answer (score 6):

Only classes implementing the Iterable interface and arrays are. Maps do not implement Iterable, instead they provide three different iterable views (key set, value collection and entry set), which you can iterate over. A more complete check would thus be:

```
return obj instanceof Iterable || obj.getClass().isArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

The JDK 1.7 Documentation in the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface lists everything within the JDK API that implements iterable, but nothing precludes a third-party library from implementing Iterable as well in any class.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Iterables also arrays (which don't implement the Iterable interface) can be used in the enhanced for loop.