# How can i return Iterable with a Function?

Tags: java, return, iterable

I have objects containing the name and the age of people. Then i built a hashtable containing those objects. I wrote my own Interfaces called PeopleIterator and PeopleIterable and the Iteratorimplementation for this hashtable. That's all working just fine.

Now I have to write a function in that hashtable-class that returns another Interface called StringIterable, that contains all the peoples names.

I can use a data structure from the Collections Framework and helper classes if i need them, but i don't even know how to start.

```java
public class PeopleHashtable implements PeopleIterable{
    private People[] people;

    public StringIterable copyNames() {

    }
}


public interface StringIterable extends java.lang.Iterable<String> {
    StringIterator iterator();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all these custom classes? You probably shouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

set and list are iterables. so maybe just return something like map.keySet().

related: [Arrays, lists, sets and maps are iterable. What else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801749/arrays-lists-sets-and-maps-are-iterable-what-else)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Iterator interface by providing implementations for `next()` and `hasNext()`.

hasNext() simply returns true or false if you have another element to return.  It could be as simple as checking the current array index to the length of the array.

next() simply returns the element at that index and increments the index.

Here's a sample template.

```java
class MyClass implements Iterator<String> {
   String[] foo ...;
   private int index;
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      index = 0;
      return this;
   }

   public boolean hasNext() {
      //your code
   }

   public String next() {
      //your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misinterpreted the requirements.  I think that `copyNames` should actually return an `Iterator<String>` not an `Iterable`.  An `Iterable` is something that you call `iterator()` on to get an `Iterator`.

And I also agree with John Klugeman's comment is correct.  It is inadvisable to declare custom interfaces like `PeopleIterable` and `StringIterable`.  They don't help.

Anyway, here is a concise implementation for `copyNames` (bad choice of method name!) assuming that it returns a `Iterator` rather than an `Iterable`.

```
public Iterator<String> copyNames() {
    return Arrays.stream(people).map(p -> p.getName()).iterator();
}
```

If you really need an `Iterable` ....

```
public Iterable<String> copyNames() {
    return new Iterable<String>() {
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return Arrays.stream(people).map(p -> p.getName()).iterator();
        }
    }
}
```